# getting un expected result in jquery onclick event

Tags: jquery

i am trying to add class on `on-click`  jquery event for that i am doing

my html file

```
<head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .red{ color:red; }
        </style>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

javascript file js.js is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("li").onclick(function(){ // if i comment this and only add the line billow the all ul>li will red
        $("#list").addClass("red");
    });
});
```

when i click on the `li` the color of `li` will become the red the thing makes me confuse that `on-click` i am adding the class `.red` to the `ul` so the both link should be red but on click only the link i clicked  become red

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing jQuery's [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method with the vanilla JavaScript [`element.onclick = functionRef;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onclick)

In your code sample, you want:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $("#list").addClass("red");
});
```

Comment: thankyou its just a simple mistake done by me because of switching from js to j query +1

Answer (score 2):

There is no jQuery function called `onclick()`. There is `on` and `click`, but no `onclick`. Your list element turns red because the link gets activated, not because of your javascript.

Use either `on`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("li").on('click', function(){
        $("#list").addClass("red");
    });
});
```

or `click`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("li").click(function(){
        $("#list").addClass("red");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), not `onclick`

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9L8C/) of it working as expected. I removed the `<a>` tags so link colors would interfere with what you're doing.